# event fire on onclick in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

cart.js

```
const Cart = () => {
const cartListing = useSelector(state => state.cartList);
const {cart, loading, error} = cartListing;
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const removeFromCartHandler = (id) => {
    dispatch(removeFromCart(id))
};  // =======>>>>> This function needs to dispatch on onclick event but it fire on first time load and does not fire on click
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(cartList());
    return () => {

    }       
},[]);
return(
<button type="button" className="button" onClick={removeFromCartHandler()} >Delete </button>
```

action.js

```
const cartList = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: CART_LIST_REQUEST });
    const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/cart');
    dispatch({ type: CART_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data.data.cartRecords });
  }
  catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: CART_LIST_FAIL, payload: error.message });
  }
};

const removeFromCart = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
 try {
    dispatch({ type: CART_REMOVE_ITEM, payload: id });
    const { data } = await axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/cart/${id}`);
    dispatch({ type: CART_REMOVE_SUCCESS, payload: data });
 }
 catch (error) {
    dispatch({type: CART_REMOVE_FAIL, payload: error.message})
 }
};

export { cartList, removeFromCart };
```

I don't know why removeFromCartHandler() is firing on first time loading, not on click. I want that removeFromCartHandler() this function fire on onclick event not on the first-time load as I have also not added in useEffect hook cartList is fine dispatching on first time but removeFromCartHandler() function need to dispatch on onClick event. I think I am missing some concept of hooks here. I am new to react-redux and stucked here. Any help will be appricated

Comment: Change `onClick={removeFromCartHandler()}` to `onClick={() => removeFromCartHandler()}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add more code for better context but what you have to do is something like this

```
onClick={(e) => removeFromCartHandler(e, item.id)}
```

your main function expects to get id you have to pass it over somehow.
I presume that you render cart items or do something similar, anyhow with this implementation proper id will not be passed.

Answer (score 2):

your onClick handler is wrong . Do it like this

```
onClick={() => removeFromCartHandler()}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's being called because **you are calling it** - placing `()` after `removeFromCartHandler` invokes the function.

```js
onClick={removeFromCartHandler()}
```